# Cache entire page in memcache and optional serve from middleware or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, memcached, middleware

I have a page that I'd like to cache in memcache. I'm on Heroku, so standard page caching isn't an option.

I want to have middleware that checks for a particular cookie value being set. If it is not there, I want to just render the value in the cache. Otherwise, I want Rails to handle it like normal and then optional server the value in the cache later in a controller (upon checking the value in the cookie).

So basically, I need a way to cache a page in memcache and serve it out later. I don't want to just use a static file so the page can take advantage of layouts, the asset pipeline, etc. So I guess **the main question is how do I render a page into memcache.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered something else than memcached for output cache? Memcached seems to me to good solution for data-caching. I knew some project that successfully implemented page-level cache using [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), though I don't know nothing about Varnish-RoR integrations, as thos projects were built using PHP

Comment: Thanks @toske. With my current setup, Varnish isn't really an option. That would definitely be a great solution though.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen great performance using caches_action with a Proc.  Try this:

```
caches_action :index, :unless => { |c| c.user_logged_in? }
```

This should serve the page from memcache if the user is not logged in. Because it's caching the action, anything in your application_controller will run first (handy, though admittedly slower). With this strategy, I've seen page loads out of memcache in the sub-10ms range. This should work great w/o needing to jump into the middleware.

If that's not enough, you might want to take a look at Rack::Cache

Comment: I don't think `caches_page` is what you want. That will [write the page to a file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb#L83) which is intended to be served by the web server (Nginx/Apache). Try action caching or better yet, some [http caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/321-http-caching) with [Rack Cache](http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/)

Comment: Strange -- I thought I'd seen caches_page write into memcache. My understanding was that the main difference between page and action caching was whether or not AppController and before_filters ran or not -- not how the data was stored. Regardless, edited to reduce any confusion. Thanks for the help, Ryan!

Answer (score 3):

[Rack::Cache](http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/) will do what you need, and it is enabled automatically in production. It uses [HTTP headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) to determine the caching behavior. You can set these headers with `fresh_when`, `stale?` and `expires_in` calls in the controller action. However it is important to set the `public: true` option for Rack::Cache to pick it up.

```
fresh_when @product, public: true
```

The cache is stored in `Rails.cache` by default, so that will need to be configured to use memcached.

A nice side effect of this approach is that, since it uses HTTP caching, the cache can be stored on the client side in their browser or on a local network proxy. This will make your site feel even faster to the user since the cache is closer.

I go into further detail [in this RailsCasts episode (paid subscription required)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/321-http-caching).

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails.cache 'somekey' do
   do_whatever
end
```

This will try to fetch the key, if it exists it will render. If not it will process the block and set the key to the value

Comment: Right, I know that. How do I render a page into `somekey`?

Comment: You could render the template directly in the block if you are dead-set on doing this in Rack. What type of templates are you using?

Comment: Ended up going with @jmccartie's solution. I'm using ERB by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Page caching does work on Heroku, but needs a bit of configuration. If you are on the bamboo stack, you already have Varnish in front of your app. If you are on Cedar, you don't, but there are still caching options for you. I suggest taking a look at:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies

There are several strategies outlined there, like page caching, action caching, fragment cacghing, etc.

You do need a caching plugin (I use memcache, but I believe there is now an alternative). If you don't need a big cache, the starter package is free.